# Is syslog.h still the way to log in modern C++?

Tags: c++, posix, syslog

`syslog.h` is the `C` library to write logs via syslog.
I saw this also in `C++` code and wonder, if there is no `C++` pendant for this and if it is still good style to include `syslog.h` in modern `C++` projects.

Many `C++` developers avoid to mix `C++` and `C`, but want to use logs.
This is why I expected a pure `C++` library for this task.

Comment: There are quite a few C++ logging frameworks, and I guess many of them have backends that can be used to write to the POSIX syslog (either using network communication or using the standard [`syslog`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/syslog.html) call).

Comment: syslog has never been in the C or C++ standard

Comment: I've been using for quite some time [spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog) and it provides a syslog backend. I'm fairly happy with it and it's available in conan and in vcpkg

Comment: I use [loguru](https://github.com/emilk/loguru). You can define logging sink (which can be syslog).